# Using sympy's latex() function without calculating the input

Tags: math, python-3.x, latex, sympy

I want to get latex output from a sympy expression without calculating the expression. For instance if I do latex((2+3)/7) the output would be 5/7 (with latex), but what I am after is for it to just output (2+3)/7 with latex.  Like this: \frac{2+3}{7}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually adjust the long_frac_ratio

> long_frac_ratio: The allowed ratio of the width of the numerator to the
>   width of the denominator before we start breaking off long fractions.
>   The default value is 2.

```
>>> latex(e,long_frac_ratio=3)
'\\frac{2 + 3}{7}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to sympify the expression with keyword `evaluate=False`:

```
>>> latex(S('(2+3)/7',evaluate=False))
'\\frac{1}{7} \\left(2 + 3\\right)'
```

Comment: I sort of found this out, but the problem is that sometimes it does some weird stuff. for instance (2+3)/7 becomes (1/7)(2+3) which is not optimal for what I need to do. (\frac{1}{7} \left(2 + 3\right)) I might just find another library for parsing latex or write my own parser.

Comment: Don't forget about the mode options:

Comment: @smichr "the mode options: "?? Also had the issue with Latex parser ignoring the `evaluate=False` too. Is there a mode options to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

(better added as another answer)

Don't forget about the mode options:

```
>>> e = S('(2+3)/7', evaluate=False)
>>> latex(e,mode='inline')
'$\\left(2 + 3\\right) / 7$'
>>> latex(e,mode='plain')
'\\frac{1}{7} \\left(2 + 3\\right)'
>>> latex(e,mode='equation')
'\\begin{equation}\\frac{1}{7} \\left(2 + 3\\right)\\end{equation}'
>>> latex(e,mode='equation*')
'\\begin{equation*}\\frac{1}{7} \\left(2 + 3\\right)\\end{equation*}'
```

Comment: appreciate the help, but adding the mode (as you can see on the latex output) still outputs wrongly. (it adds (2+3) on the right of 1/7 instead of outputting (2+3)/7. Also setting evaluate to false still calculates multiplication which is also something I do not want to do. I've already made a workaround that does not use sympy, but I'm still kinda interested in if this is even possible in sympy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fold_short_frac option is what you are looking for?

```
>>> latex(S('(2+3)/7',evaluate=False), fold_short_frac=True)
'\\left(2 + 3\\right) / 7'
```

Also, not sure what you mean about the evaluate=False not working for Mul. Perhaps you can give an example.

```
>>> S('2*3',evaluate=False)
2*3
>>> S('2*3/7',evaluate=False)
2*3/7
```

Comment: Found out why I thought it was multiplying. I was checking stuff in the liveshell which seem to do calculations when outputting answers. so S('2*3/7',evaluate=False) returns 6/7, but if i print it instead it shows 2*3/7. Also fold_short_frac is definitely not what I'm looking for since I want frac to be used. Specifically the answer to my question would be to get the latex() function to output this: \frac{2+3}{7}