# Converting fraction using numerals to a string which uses \\frac{}{} Latex format

Tags: python, latex, sympy

Is there a way to convert a string written in this format:
`str = "9+3/3+6/2"`

To a Latex string that looks like this:
`"9 + \frac{3}{3} + \frac{6}{2}"`

As `sympy.latex(str)` returns the original string and if I pass `sympy.latex(9+3/3+6/2)`, an evaluated value of 13 is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parameter *evaluate=False* while creating a *SymPy* object, this prevents the expression from being evaluated:

```
In [1]: expr = sympify("9+3/3+6/2", evaluate=False)

In [2]: expr
Out[2]: 
3   6    
- + - + 9
3   2    

In [3]: latex(expr)
Out[3]: '\\frac{3}{3} + \\frac{6}{2} + 9'

In [4]: print (latex(expr))
\frac{3}{3} + \frac{6}{2} + 9
```

Comment: I found a similar solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543995/using-sympys-latex-function-without-calculating-the-input which was helpful as well. Thanks.